How to make tcbox (from tcolorbox) breakable with correct hyphenation?
I'm working on a LaTeX document where I use a custom tcbox command to style parts of my text. However, I want the content within these boxes to be breakable and to support proper hyphenation, as sometimes the text within the box exceeds the line width. Currently, the box does not break, and words that go off the line are not hyphenated, causing layout problems.
Here's a minimal working example of my current code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newlength{\tagboxwidth}
\newcommand{\tagbox}[4][orange]{%
  \settowidth{\tagboxwidth}{\hspace{3pt}\sffamily#3\hspace{3pt}}%
  \tcbox[enhanced, nobeforeafter, tcbox raise base, boxrule=0.4pt, top=0mm, bottom=0mm, right=0mm, left=\tagboxwidth, arc=1pt, boxsep=2pt, before upper={\vphantom{dlg}}, colframe=#1, coltext=#2, colback=#1!10, overlay={
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
      \fill[#1] (frame.south west)
      rectangle node[text=white, font=\sffamily]{#3\vphantom{dlg}}([xshift=\tagboxwidth]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}
  }]%
  {#4}%
}

\MakeRobust\tagbox

\ifdefined\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\tagbox#1{'#1'}}
\fi

\newcommand{\content}[2]{%
  \tagbox[orange]{orange}{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

Among the 12 works was the \content{Content}{National Gallery's Japanese Footbridge}. [...] More telling, the impenetrable green enclosure -- heightened the \content{Content}{National Gallery painting} by the placement of the top [...]

\end{document}

At the moment it looks like this:

However, I want it to look like this:


You could try to adapt my answer from here using soulpos and tcolorbox
